# Populate a CellTree with ListDataProvider

Tags: java, gwt

I'm currently developing a custom Tree in GWT (extending **AbstractEListViewer**)

I want to populate a `CellTree` with a `ListDataProvider`, but I can't do it like I do it for a `CellList`, by using `AbstractDataProvider.addDataDisplay(HasData<SomeClass>)` because `CellTree` doesn't implements `HasData<T>` ..

Variables :

```
protected transient CellTree treeViewer;
protected static ListDataProvider<SomeClass> provider;
```

Code :

```
@Override
protected Widget createViewer(EWidgetInit init, Container parent) {
    TreeViewModel model = new CustomTreeModel();
    treeViewer = new CellTree(model, null);

    provider = new ListDataProvider<SomeClass>();
    provider.addDataDisplay(treeViewer); // not applicable for the arguments (CellTree)

    return treeViewer.asWidget();
}
```

Error :

**The method addDataDisplay(HasData) in the type AbstractDataProvider is not applicable for the arguments (CellTree)**

At the moment, Tree is displayed on the webpage but it displays "empty", as it is not populated of course:

Does anybody know how to populate this CellTree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this problem by deleting this line:

```
    provider.addDataDisplay(treeViewer); // not applicable for the arguments (CellTree)
```

and instantiating `ListDataProvider` before the `CellTree`.